# Byte align BitVector after decoding misaligned value

Tags: scala, scodec

I've come across an interesting problem with scodec. I have a peculiar encoding scheme that requires a stream byte alignment when the current bit pointer mod 8 is not zero (not aligned to the nearest byte).

Now normally, this would be handled by the `byteAligned` codec, but the situation appears to need *global* context of the entire decoding operation.

Here's a minimal example of the problem

```
case class Baz(abc : Int, qux : Int)  
case class Foo(bar : Int,
               items : Vector[Baz])

object Foo {
   implicit val codec : Codec[Foo] = (
      ("bar" | uint8L) ::
      ("items" | vectorOfN(uint8L, (
            ("abc" | uint8L) ::
            ("qux" | uint2L)
         ).as[Baz]
      ))).as[Foo]
}
```

`items` will be encoded and decoded as a `Vector` of `Baz` items. Notice that the `qux` member in `Baz` is represented as a 2-bit unsigned int. We want the `abc` member to be *byte aligned*, meaning that during it's decoding, it will decode and if the byte stream is misaligned, padding must be added after the decoded bits (Case C).

This means for a vector of size 1 (Case A), the output BitVector will be misaligned by 6-bits, which is fine because there are no more items (`abc` is never reached again in the vector decoding loop).

A vector of size 2  without byte aligning is shown in Case B.
A vector *with* byte aligning is shown in Case C.

Below each case is comment breaking down the bitstream. `0x0a` is hex for 10 decimal and `0b01` is binary for 1 decimal. I will switch between the two when more detail is needed and when the stream isn't byte aligned.

**Case A**

```
Codec.encode(Foo(10, Vector(Baz(4,1))))
res43: Attempt[BitVector] = Successful(BitVector(26 bits, 0x0a01044))
// bar  N items   abc(0)  qux(0)
// 0x0a   0x01     0x04    0b01
```

**Case B**

```
Codec.encode(Foo(10, Vector(Baz(4,1), Baz(15,3))))
res42: Attempt[BitVector] = Successful(BitVector(36 bits, 0x0a020443f))
// bar  N items   abc(0)  qux(0)    abc(1)    qux(1)
// 0x0a   0x02     0x04    0b01   0b00001111   0b11
```

**Case C**

```
Codec.encode(Foo(10, Vector(Baz(4,1), Baz(15,3))))
res42: Attempt[BitVector] = Successful(BitVector(42 bits, 0x0a020443c0c))
// bar  N items   abc(0)  qux(0)    abc(1)    padding   qux(1)
// 0x0a   0x02     0x04    0b01   0b00001111  0b000000   0b11
```

Another way of looking at Case C is unrolling the codecs

```
// bar     N items   abc(0)     qux(0)   abc(1)    padding       qux(1)
(uint8L :: uint8L :: uint8L :: uint2L :: uint8L :: ignore(6) :: uint2L).
   dropUnits.encode(10 :: 2 :: 4 :: 1 :: 15 :: 3 :: HNil)
res47: Attempt[BitVector] = Successful(BitVector(42 bits, 0x0a020443c0c))
```

Notice that there wasn't any padding after `abc(0)` as the stream was byte aligned at that point. At `abc(1)` it was not aligned due to the decoding of `qux(0)`. After the alignment, `qux` will be decoding on an aligned boundary. We always want `qux` to decode on a byte aligned position.

What I need is some method to either get a global context to figure out if the current bit pointer in the overall BitVector is aligned. If not, I need a codec to intelligently know when it's not decoding on an aligned boundary and to correct the stream after decoding it's current value.

I know codecs can get the *current* bitstream to decode from, but they have no idea about where they are in an overall bitstream.

Any direction or code would be most appreciated.

**P.S.**

If you want to test in Ammonite you'll need this to start

```
load.ivy("org.scodec" %% "scodec-core" % "1.8.3")
import scodec.codecs._
import scodec._
import shapeless._
```

When copying and pasting, you'll need to start with a `{` to make sure the case class and case object get defined at the same time.